# I have hit a wall on my first proper project

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

First off, english is not my native language. I'm from Norway and therefore I might phrase my english poorly or whatnot. If I do so I apologize.

Seeing as this is my first project I decided to create something easy and as such I landed on a simple quote generator. The functionality is contained within the Javascript file and that is where to problem lies. I have created an array with all my quotes (right now it only contains three words for testing purposes), when you hit the button then a quote is supposed to be displayed inside of a box on screen. The thing is that nothing happens when you click the button and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I have tried to write the code both in Sublime and in VS Code just to see if that has something to do with it, but it doesn't seem to. VS code displays these two errors in a couple of places: ',' expected ts and declaration or statement expected. Unfortunatly I am not experienced enough to realize what these mean. When you take a look at the code, keep in mind that the comments as well as the text that should be displayed is written in my native tongue. If you would like me to translate then I would gladly do so.  I am getting quite frustrated as I've tried to figure it out for a long time now. I would be immensly grateful for any help  you are willing to offer me.

```js
function clicked(

//Her er banken med sitatene
let quotes = ["Test 1", "test 2", "test 3",]

// Denne velger ut et tilfeldig sitat
let = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

// Denne omgjør det tilfeldige sitatet til HTML
document.getElementByID("output").innerHTML = quotes_random;
)
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #90dcff;
}


#container {
    height: 275px;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid #673B90;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#F5A01F;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    align-self: center;




}


#btn {
    background-color: #fdfb76;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: relative;
    top: 250px;
    align-self: center;
}

#btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    background-color: #e10086;
}



#output {
    margin: 25px auto;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -120px;
    align-self: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


        
    <div id="container">
        <button onclick="clicked()" id="btn">Trykk her for et visdomord</button>
     </div>
        

     <p

      id="output">Trykk på knappen for å generere et visdomsord
    </p> 

     <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `function clicked() { /* ...*/ }`

Comment: ^ That and code has other syntax errors. `let = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];` has a syntax error in `let =`, the identifier for the variable name is missing.

Comment: Please write a title that summarizes the specific problem: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems with your code.

1. The syntax for a function is `function name(paramters) {code}`, not `function name(code)`
2. You can't just have `let` without a reference name. You forgot `quotes_random` on that line.
3. You misspelled `document.getElementById` as `document.getElementByID`. The last `d` is small as it is camel-case structure all the way.

```js
function clicked() {
  //Her er banken med sitatene
  let quotes = ["Test 1", "test 2", "test 3", ];
  // Denne velger ut et tilfeldig sitat
  let quotes_random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]; //let = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  // Denne omgjør det tilfeldige sitatet til HTML
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = quotes_random; //document.getElementByID("output").innerHTML = quotes_random;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button onclick="clicked()" id="btn">Trykk her for et visdomord</button>
</div>


<p id="output">Trykk på knappen for å generere et visdomsord</p>
```

I would suggest opening the developer console on your web browser of choice (Typically by pressing F12).

This will tell you where the JavaScript interpreter fails to understand your code.